# I'm trying to use the Bluebird's method Promisify and it's not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm not able to make a simple example works on bluebird. I've used the **new** **Promise** method and it works, but when I try to use the Promisify method I may be doing something wrong.

```
exports.makeRequest = function(someText){
    return Promise.resolve(someText);
}

var makeRequestAsync = Promise.promisify(exports.makeRequest);

makeRequestAsync('Testing').then(function(data){
    console.log(data); // --> log never appears
});
```

I really want to understand how promisify works.

Comment: You don't need to promisify it. Just call `makeRequest`, it already returns a resolved promise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bluebird's `promisify()` only works with node-style functions that take a callback as their last argument where that callback takes two arguments, an error and the data.  Your function does not meet this criteria.

You can read about how it works [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function).

In addition, there's no need to promisify a function that already returns a promise.  You can just call that function directly and use its returned promise since it's already a promise returning function.

```
exports.makeRequest = function(someText){
    return Promise.resolve(someText);
}

exports.makeRequest('Testing').then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n01zyqc6/

---

Of course, since your function isn't actually async, there doesn't appear to be any reason to even use promises with it at all.

---

Here's an example of actually promisifying something that is async and uses the right calling convention:

```
exports.myFunc = function(data, callback) {
    // make the result async
    setTimeout(function() {
        // call the callback with the node style calling convention
        callback(0, data);
    }, 500);

};

var myFuncAsync = Promise.promisify(exports.myFunc);

myFuncAsync("Hello").then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank You! But how could I make the function work with promisify in this example?

Comment: @ElvioCavalcante - first off, there is no point in using promisify with your own function that is not async like you have.  You already wrote it to work with promises so there's no need to further promisify it.  Second off, if you read the link I've posted, you just have to make your function follow the `nodeFunction` convention described there before you can call promisify on it.  promisify only works on functions that follow a specific calling convention and then they have to invoke their callback with the right arguments when they are done with their work.

Comment: @ElvioCavalcante - we would probably all be better off if you described the real problem you're trying to solve rather than trying to promisify a function that is already promise compatible so there's no need to promisify it.

Comment: @ElvioCavalcante - I added an example to my answer of promisifying something that is async and follows the proper calling convention to work with `.promisify()`.

Comment: Thank you!! It definitely works. I fully understand how promisify works. :)